# Accidentally closed my status bar in Firefox 5. How do I get it back?

Tags: firefox, statusbar

I accidentally closed my status bar in Firefox 5. Can I get it back? How do I show my status bar again?

I can't seem to find the option anywhere.

Comment: *> Please don't remove unnessaray items* -- sorry, this is *very* common. Please see: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Brett: @slhck is correct, I have edited this out to reflect Super User's policy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean the Add-on Bar. The status bar has been replaced by the `View > Toolbars > Add-on Bar` that extensions can use.

Note: The status bar shows up when it has something to say. If you hover over a link, it will show up to tell you where the link goes and if a page is being loaded, it will show up to display the status of the transfer.

Comment: Ahh I found it. That was it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

It can also be toggled with the `Control`+`/` shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Right-click on the top bar as shown in image and select `Add-on Bar`